# Make buttons appear in the middle of the page bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys i have 2 buttons right now:

```
 <a href="GAME1/index.html" class="btn btn-warning" style ="margin-left: 500px;">1 Player</a>
  <a href="GAME4/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">2 Players</a>
```

Trying to make them appear in the middle of my page, however i am sure using things like margin-left 500px is not good coding, i was wondering what is the best way to make them appear in the middle of the page and also 1 above the other , and change the size of the buttons and make them a little bigger

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both buttons in a div like so

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a href="GAME1/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">1 Player</a>
  <a href="GAME4/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">2 Players</a>
</div>
```

If you want them one above the other, add `style="display: block;"` to each button. To change the font size, add a `font-size` to your inline styles.

So now:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a href="GAME1/index.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="display:block; font-size: 20px;">1 Player</a>
  <a href="GAME4/index.html" class="btn btn-warning" style="display:block; font-size: 20px;">2 Players</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

---

```html
<div id="buttonCenter" style="text-align:center"> 
<a href="GAME1/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">1 Player</a>
<a href="GAME4/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">2 Players</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah they are still side by side and, also sorry how do u make the text bigger?

Comment: You can use style="display:block; font-size:14px;" on each of the <a> tag. You can change the font-size value to whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap comes with a class named "text-center".
This will center the div and any content inside of it.

```
<div class="text-center"> 
    <a href="GAME1/index.html" class="btn btn-warning" style ="margin-left:     500px;">1 Player</a>
    <a href="GAME4/index.html" class="btn btn-warning">2 Players</a>
</div>
```